# How to break a span text in two lines using css? (word-wrap/ word-break doesnt work)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, line

```
<ul className="aboutMiniContent">
                    <li className='aboutSingleMini'><a href=""><img src={aboutMiniImg1} alt="" /></a>
                        <span>conventional fruits</span></li>
</ul>
```

that's my code now I that span text to 2 lines first line will get "conventional" and the 2nd line will get "fruits" how ? I mean in CSS. I have used word-wrap and word-break, doesn't work